# Is this endpoint (flask+sqlalchemy+sqlite) going to bottleneck on large amounts of data?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm trying to build a practice API with Flask. The thing is I'm trying to address if this endpoint is going to have problems with large amounts of rows in the database.

So far the only thing that I'm identifying that has to do with the input size are the queries and serialization. Instead of query.all() I can use a couple columns less, but that's the only thing I have come up with.

Any ideas?

```py
@app.route(PREFIX + '/games', methods=['GET'])
def get_games():
    games_list = []
    if len(request.args) == 0:
        all_games = Game.query.all()
        result = games_schema.dump(all_games)

        for g in result:
            games_list.append(
                Feature(geometry=g["geometry"], properties=g["properties"]))

        games_fc = FeatureCollection(games_list)
        return jsonify(games_fc)

    else:
        filters = {key: value for key, value in request.args.items() if key in [
            "category", "location", "district"]}

        allowed_categories = []
        allowed_locations = []
        allowed_districts = []

        for c in db.session.query(Game.category).distinct():
            allowed_categories.append(c.category)

        for l in db.session.query(Game.location).distinct():
            allowed_locations.append(l.location)

        for d in db.session.query(Game.district).distinct():
            allowed_districts.append(d.district)

        for key, value in filters.items():
            if key == "category":
                if value not in allowed_categories:
                    abort(400, "You enetered a non-valid category")
            elif key == "location":
                if value not in allowed_locations:
                    abort(400, "You entered a non-valid location")
            elif key == "district":
                if value not in allowed_districts:
                    abort(400, "You entered a non-valid district")

        filtered_game = Game.query.filter_by(**filters)
        result = games_schema.dump(filtered_game)
        for g in result:
            games_list.append(
                Feature(geometry=g["geometry"], properties=g["properties"]))

        games_fc= FeatureCollection(games_list)
        return jsonify(games_fc)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't bother with performance problems you may have in the future. You will always *never* guess what the real bottlenecks will be.

Assuming you have a bottleneck, there are several things you could refactor:

- Don't look up category, location, and district. It is expensive and you just use it only for your error message. If there are no matches, just return an empty result.
- If you still want to look up category etc. then put an index in your database on these columns. That should speed up the lookups considerably.
- Lastly, you could switch to [streaming](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/) your response, if you fear that the receiver has not enough memory to process the response.